# How to Disable (Not Hide) Table Rows

Tags: html

I need to disable (not hide) a single table row in a table with at least two rows.  I've been searching for how to do it, but everything I've found tells me how to hide the row.  I need to actually disable it so that the result is not submitted.

I'm using a template row and cloning when users add rows.  On submit, the hidden template and the rows with actual data are all submitted.  The database save fails because the hidden row doesn't pass validation.

```
<tr class="template" style="display:none"> 
<!-- This is the row to be copied and unhidden to add to the table -->
    <td>company</td>
    <td>department</td>
    <td>line</td>
    <td>account</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can disable `input` (and `textarea`) elements, *not* table-rows. What's your relevant HTML, and what, exactly, do you want to do? In response to what? If you want to do this dynamically (in response to a user's actions, perhaps) then you'll need to use JavaScript to add/remove the `disabled` property of the appropriate elements within the `tr` element(s).

Comment: There are a variety of solutions, but we would need to see the code that is submitting and the HTML first.

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is my first question.  I added HTML above.  I don't want to submit the hidden row.

Comment: There are no submittable elements in the code snippet in the question. Please post some *real* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are going to duplicate the table row over and over again to create the table structure with javascript or something. Options:

You could remove the row from the DOM before submission or

```
jQuery('tr.template').remove();
```

you could select all the rows except it to submit

```
jQuery('table tr').not('tr.template').submit();
```

Comment: $('tr.template').remove(); did the trick.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I personally do not think it is possible to have a table without rows, perhaps you mean you want to stylise your website without using a table?
If that is the case, then if your not already, set up a css file, with this you can edit and manipulate blocks for your website. ( I would post screenshots but my reputation isn't up yet ^-^ )

Comment: Not really an answer. The part that looks like a conditional answer does not address the question asked.